# Перенос гиперссылок в OpenOffice Calc

Tags: open-office, libre-office

Лист OpenOffice Calc содержит набор наименований в столбце, например "А", где на каждой из строк установлена внешняя ссылка на сайт.

Для импорта в БД необходимо добавить ссылки на изображения отдельно от наименований.

Какой макрос должен переместить прямые ссылки в соседний от наименования столбец?

Версия пакета: Apache OpenOffice 4.12

Answer (score 0):

Решено этой функцией на Microsoft Excel

```
Function Get_Hyperlink_Address(ByVal rCell As Range) As String
    Dim s As String
    If rCell.Hyperlinks.Count = 0 Then
        If Mid$(rCell.Formula, 2, 9) = "HYPERLINK" Then
            Get_Hyperlink_Address = Mid$(rCell.Formula, 13, InStr(13, rCell.Formula, Chr(34)) - 13)
        Else
            Get_Hyperlink_Address = "В ячейке нет гиперссылки!"
        End If
    Else
        s = rCell.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
        If s <> "" Then s = "#" & rCell.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
        Get_Hyperlink_Address = rCell.Hyperlinks(rCell.Hyperlinks.Count).Address & s
    End If
End Function
```

Далее, путём обращения к каждой ячейке `=Get_Hyperlink_Address(A1)`

Comment: О! У них всё-таки есть нормальная объектная модель?